# Access denied when using Directory.Move() in impersonation with UserLogon with Interactive

Tags: windows

When I try to perform `Directory.Move()` I get error

> System.IO.IOException  ... Access Denied

Steps to reproduce:

1. Run Visual Studio 2013 at console with `PsExec.exe -s -d -i` which could assign system privilege to my program. (When running `System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name` gives `NT AUTHORITY\\SYSTEM`)
2. LogonUser with LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE and invoke `ImpersonateLoggedOnUser()` - no error returned
3. `Directory.Move(myfolderAtProgramData,myfolderAtProgramData+"_")`
4. VS throws a `System.IO.IOException` - 'Access Denied'

If LogonUser with LOGON32_LOGON_NEW_CREDENTIALS then it works. **Why??**

Below are references for my implementation:

1. [What is the difference: LoadUserProfile -vs- RegOpenCurrentUser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/459248/what-is-the-difference-loaduserprofile-vs-regopencurrentuser)
2. [Impersonation to get user HKEY_CURRENT_USER does not work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1429837/impersonation-to-get-user-hkey-current-user-does-not-work)
3. [Access CurrentUser Registry Key for Impersonated User - Compatibility with .NET 3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16477370/access-currentuser-registry-key-for-impersonated-user-compatibility-with-net)
4. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/fd531413-1ea9-4141-bba8-c1c5e9270001/access-currentuser-registry-key-for-impersonated-user-compatibility-with-net-35?forum=csharpgeneral

Environment:

> Win10 Pro 64bit ,EN ,Visual Studio 2013 , .Net4.0 , c#
>   A folder at ProgramData (allow modification only with administrator privilege)

Comment: It doesn't work because [the token you get from LogonUser doesn't have administrator access](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39403050/886887).  But since the program is running as local system, and therefore already has the necessary access to move the folder in question, why are you impersonating at all?

Comment: Harry, really fast response ,Thanks !! I type "System.Security.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrentName()" after impersonation , "DESKTOP-3FGNMSD\\Admin" is returned ,which is my adminstrator account. Why can't i move directory ??DO you think some privileges are removed than that from LogonUser() with Interactive ?? (Even i know System account could, i want to figure out)

Comment: Yes.  As described in the question and answer I linked to, LogonUser() is affected by UAC; administrator rights are removed.  If you need a token with admin privilege, use `LOGON32_LOGON_BATCH` instead.

Comment: Harry  , Thanks . Your suggest would be tried.